# Как перенести БД, созданную с помощью Entity Framework, на удаленный хост?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity

Есть база данных, созданная с использованием Entity Framework, как можно перенести ее на удаленный хост и подключиться к ней с локальной машины?

Использую Сode First. 
Прикрепляю connection string.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Data Source= (localdb)\MsSqlLocalDb; Initial Catalog=DB; Integrated Security = SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Pooling=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Подход `Code First` используете?

Comment: Да, сейчас уточню в вопросе

Comment: Значит вопрос в переносе данных?

Comment: Бекап/рестор средствами ssms, корректировка app.conf -- вот и всё, ничего особенного.

Comment: Нужно перенести БД на удаленный хост так, чтобы я с локальной машины мог вносить и доставать оттуда данные. Главное - перенести БД.

Comment: Правый клик - Restore database, далее выбрать bak-файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По шагам

- (этот шаг нужен только если БД не подключена) Правый клик на списке БД и выбрать пункт `Подключить` или `Attach`. Указать путь к папке с БД.
- Сделать на локальном хосте резервную копию БД средствами sql server management studio
- Залить на удалённый хост (восстановление БД работает только с локальных дисков)
- Восстановить на удалённом хосте БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Запустить процедуру remapping'а SID учёток

> sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'dbuser', 'dbuser'

- Поправить в app.config строку подключения (как минимум, параметр Data source - имя хоста или его IP-адрес; возможно, что ещё и user/login нужно будет прописать иной)

  ```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myserver01;Initial Catalog=database_name_here;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  ```

Comment: Менеджер не находит мою БД. Сейчас добавлю connection string в вопрос

Comment: @EssenceZen А, кстати: уточните, как у вас локальная БД создана? Что в app.conf стоит, часом не ```Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-```

Comment: @EssenceZen У вас база не приаттачена. Добавил нулевым пунктом в ответ.

Comment: Подключил, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: @AK приаттачена у него база, к (localdb)\MsSqlLocalDb. Просто в management studio надо подключаться именно к этому инстансу

Comment: @PashaPash Кстати, да. SQL Express, именованные инстансы... Забываю иногда, что есть мир и за пределами энтерпрайза.